# Animation over the view with cocoa drawing

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation, drawing

everybody! I perform cocoa drawing in view and perform some animation (moving text label) over this view. During the animation content in my view breaks:

before animation:

[image]

after animation:

[image]

How to improve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I replace dirtyRect with self.bounds:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

     NSRect mainFrame = dirtyRect; ////  <--- replace dirtyRect with self.bounds
     //....drawing code
}
```